# speeding up fuzzy string matching using regex module for large dataset

Tags: regex, python-3.x, fuzzy-search

I am trying to find fuzzy matches to protein sequences and working on large dataset 500,000 items. I will have to get fuzzy matches for each one of these 500,000 against the entire dataset (500,000). It takes 1.5 seconds per item which would take days to run.

```
import regex
record = 'MAKKIVSDLDLLFSHLGKVKEESDKAKLTLRPVAEDLSKKLDKEVVFIIGGGMAYTFLKADKIDFAKDLLEKHGAKITKLFADELEGAHTVVWNGPMGVFEFGNFAQGTIGVCKAIANLKDAITIIGGGDSAAAAISLGFGK'
record_pattern = '('+record+')'+"{1<=e<=3}"
r = regex.compile(record_pattern)
newlist = list(filter(r.match, dict_keys_list)) #dict_keys_list is the 500,000 dataset
len_list = len(newlist)
```

Comment: Please can you show a sample of the dataset? And can you describe how fuzzily you want to match? I.e. please show examples of fuzzy matches.

Comment: So the strings that I want to capture will be different for up to 3 errors (insertion, deletion, substitution) for example:
string:
MNIHEYQGKEIFRSMGVAVPEGRVAFTAEEAVEKAKELNSDVYVVKAQIHAGGRIAFNINIPKKSVNKAAKFLLALYNVFIEKDCSIVEINPLVTTADGDVLALDAKINF
-------
its fuzzy variant will be exactly the same except for this part:
NIPKESVN where KK was changed to KE

So I take each string and look for fuzzy matches (upto 3 errors) in a list of 500K strings (called dict_keys_list). and will do that for the 500K strings. strings are of different sizes (25-9000 characters) I am just showing an example here

Comment: @James I added the requested example of data